# Google optimize A/B testing global CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, optimization

I have a question regarding Google Optimize CSS code. I want to A/B test button colors across the whole website ([www.interica.si](http://www.interica.si)) on Wordpress platform. When I change the CSS code in the edit mode it looks like it impacts every button but when I start running experience it changes only the Index page. Can any of you please help me? Is there a possibility to insert javascript for global change? All help is welcome.

Greetings.

Here is the code:

```
.checkout-button button alt wc-forward .current .breadcrumb-step, [data-icon-label]::after, .button#place_order, .button.checkout, .checkout-button, .single_add_to_cart_button.button, .button.single_add_to_cart_button, .button.is-outline, input[type="submit"].is-outline, input[type="reset"].is-outline, input[type="button"].is-outline {
  border : 0.25px solid rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
  background-color : rgb(209, 10, 40) !important;
  color : rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the shared CSS code seems to work just fine.

```html
.checkout-button button alt wc-forward .current .breadcrumb-step, [data-icon-label]::after, .button#place_order, .button.checkout, .checkout-button, .single_add_to_cart_button.button, .button.single_add_to_cart_button, .button.is-outline, input[type="submit"].is-outline, input[type="reset"].is-outline, input[type="button"].is-outline {
  border : 0.25px solid rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
  background-color : rgb(209, 10, 40) !important;
  color : rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
}
```

Please open up your desired **Container** & go to the Details tab.

To solve your issue, follow the next steps:

**1. Step:** Under **Page targeting** section and click "Edit Condition".

**2. Step:** Set Host to does not contain

**3. Step:** Enter your desired website address & click save.

It should solve your issue. If you have any questions or problems feel free & contact me.

Greetings